# Работа с посетителями в BGL

Tags: boost-bgl, boost, библиотеки, c++

Доброго времени суток всем!
Есть проект, который занимается созданием электрических схем. Он включает в себя несколько библиотек, одна из которых предназначена для построения неориентированного графа по схеме, а так же для различных операций над получившимся графом. 
Для работы с графом была выбрана библиотека BGL. Построение самого графа не вызывает сложностей. Но они появляются, когда дело доходит, например, до поиска в глубину.
В BGL реализован механизм посетителей, который позволяет пользователям создавать свои visitor’ы, на основе существующих классов поиска (или любых других). Т. е. пользователь библиотеки создаёт у себя посетитель, вызывает библиотечную функцию с передачей ей этого посетителя, а она уже затем разбирается, как его использовать. Всё бы хорошо, но библиотека не должна ничего знать о посетителе пользователя. Поэтому перед передачей посетителя в библиотеку его нужно присвоить указателю на базовый класс поиска. 
Я набросал код, который показывает, как это должно работать, никакой библиотеки тут нет, просто вместо неё используется передача посетителя в поток.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> graph;

// пользовательский посетитель
class custom_dfs_visitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor
{
public:
    custom_dfs_visitor() {}
    template <typename Vertex, typename Graph>
    void discover_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g) const
    {   // вывод результата поиска
        std::cout << u << std::endl;
    }
};

// вместо библиотеки используется поток 
void thread_foo(boost::default_dfs_visitor *vis, const graph& g)
{
    boost::depth_first_search(g, visitor(*vis)); // ф-я поиска в глубину
    // в данном случае в *vis будет находиться boost::base_visitor<boost::null_visitor> и поэтому поиск не сработает
}

int main()
{
    graph g; // создаём граф

    // добавляем вершины и рёбра
    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(0, 2, g);
    add_edge(1, 3, g);
    add_edge(0, 4, g);

    custom_dfs_visitor vis; // создаём экземпляр пользовательского посетителя
    boost::default_dfs_visitor* p_vis = &vis; // пакуем в указатель на базовый класс
    std::thread th(thread_foo, p_vis, g); // передаём данные в поток
    th.detach();

    // выполняем какие-то другие операции

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот как бы сделать так, чтобы библиотека, ничего не зная о пользовательском посетителе, всё же могла его использовать для алгоритма поиска?
Спасибо :)

Comment: обычно в таких случаях уточняется, как можно сравнивать элементы - например, передается внешняя функция-предикат, которая умеет сравнивать два элемента или перекрываются операторы ==,<= и тому подобное. Читайте вывод компилятора, там должны быть подсказки.

Comment: В данном случае никаких ошибок компиляции нет, просто в указателе на базовый класс находится не то, что нужно. А про функцию-предикат я не понял, можно привести пример?

Comment: я не работал с этой библиотекой, поэтому не могу дать примера.

Comment: Эх.. жаль.. Ну мож ещё кто подскажет..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Во-первых, в момент разыменования указателя `visitor(*vis)` у вас произошла [**срезка**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) объекта.

> Указатель `vis` на самом деле указывал на объект `custom_dfs_visitor,` но `*vis` уже является объектом типа `boost::default_dfs_visitor`

- Во-вторых, `Depth First Search` в `BGL` реализован как алгоритм от шаблонного параметра `DFSVisitor,` соответственно, полиморфизм здесь реализуется за счет **инстанциирования шаблонов,** а не засчет использования виртуальных функций.

> - Если посмотреть [`http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp,`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp) то можно заметить, что эвенты визитора типа `initialize_vertex` не виртуальны (да и это было бы чрезвычайно накладно в такой высокопроизводительной библиотеке, как `BGL`).
> - Наследование от `boost::default_dfs_visitor` (как, скажем, в примере [`http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/example/dfs-example.cpp)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/example/dfs-example.cpp) применяется же только из соображений уменьшения количества `boilerplate` кода.

- Вернемся к вашей задаче (как я понял, она заключается в том, чтобы допустить возможность использования абстрактных `visitor'ов` в коде методов вашей библиотеки).

> - Так вот, она довольно нетривиальная, опять же, из-за разницы между шаблонным полиморфизмом и полиморфизмом с применением виртуальных функций.
> - **Правильный** вариант решения - изменить архитектуру вашей библиотеки / ваших библиотек таким образом, чтобы она работала с шаблонными визиторами и устраивать `interop` с помощью шаблонов *(правда, этот вариант сложен для применения в случае `legacy` кода и может быть в принципе невозможным в некоторых случаях)*.
> - **Альтернативный** вариант - передавать в вашу библиотеку набор строготипизированных `std::function` и уже на месте оборачивать их с помощью `make_dfs_visitor.` См. [`http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/EventVisitorList.html`.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/EventVisitorList.html) Понятно, что в этом случае вы лишаетесь преимуществ шаблонных `<V, E>` визиторов, однако получаете возможность использовать виртуальные функции, и такой подход не требует концептуальных изменений уже существующего кода.

Comment: Да уж, вот это пища для размышлений :)) Я немного не понял некоторые вещи пока, но думаю, что если над этим подумать подольше, то что-нибудь получится. Спасибо за указание правильного направления, @Котик_хочет_кушать ! Если у меня что-то не получится, то теперь я знаю кого спросить :)